# SpringBoot JUnit and @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4

In my configuration class I have

```
@Value("${some.vars}")
private List<String> vars;
```

Now in my test I want to be able to set the value of this so I have this

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

 @Test
 public void test() {
   ApplicationContextRunner runner = new ApplicationContextRunner();
   runner
   .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(MyConfiguration.class))
   .withUserConfiguration(UserConfiguration.class)
   .withPropertyValues("some.vars=A,B,C")
   .run(ctx -> {
     // some test assertions
   }); 
 }
```

I am getting `A,B,C` as a one string binded to `List<String>` in its 0th position. I expect it to render and bind as List in `vars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extra work to split string as list

```
@Value("#{'${some.vars}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> vars;
```

Comment: Great!! how can I setup default value as #{null} here as well?

Comment: I checked but I do not know how this combination will work with split call and default value.

Comment: What do you mean null ? List<String> vars is null ? or you wnat List<String> vars is empty?

Comment: I want to set `vars` to `null` by default.

Comment: what do you mean b y default? if you don't have value for that property in yml it will be null @user3833308

Comment: I want to setup default value to `A.B.C,D.E.F`. For that I am doing this `@Value("#{'${some.vars:A.B.C,D.E.F}'.split(',')}") ` but the value it ends up setting is `` empty string. @Deadpool

Comment: check this once `{some.vars:A,B,C,D,E,F}` it should have `,` not `.` periods @user3833308

Comment: can you give me entire expression please @Deadpool and how is it different that what I have?

Comment: I think @user3833308 want "A.B.C","D.E.F" as two string